# How to patch the return value of initializing a class in Python?

Tags: python, testing, mocking, pytest

I am trying to override the value of an initialized object to a preset value for a unit test. I am using the mock library long with pytest.

Here is code that demonstrates the problem:

```
def function_to_test():
    new_object = Object(arg1, arg2, arg3)

    return func1(new_object)
```

For this function, I want to test that the object is initialized with `arg1`, `arg2`, and `arg3`, but I also want to patch the value of `new_object`, so I can test that `func1` is called with specific arguments.

My current test is something like:

```
def test_function_to_test(mocker):
    mocker.patch(Object.__init__, return_value=None)
    mocker.patch(func1)

    function_to_test()
    
    Object.__init__.assert_called_once_with(arg1, arg2, arg3)
    
    mock_object = "test"

    func1.assert_called_once_with(mock_object) # this line fails
```

For the last line to pass, the value of new_object needs to be patched to a preset value. I have tried changing the `return_value` for patching the initializer, but because the `__init__` function does not return anything, I get an error. Is there a way I can make the initialization of `Object' return a predefined value?

Comment: Where (in which modules) are `Object`, `func1` and `function_to_test` located?

Comment: func1 and function_to_test are in the same module, and Object is in a separate module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set the return value, just let it auto-generate another mock as return value. Then you can also *use* that same return value in your subsequent assertion.

It will look something like this:

```
from mymod import function_to_test

def test_function_to_test(mocker):
    mock_Object = mocker.patch("mymod.Object")
    mock_func1 = mocker.patch("mymod.func1")
    function_to_test()
    mock_Object.assert_called_once_with(arg1, arg2, arg3)
    mock_func1.assert_called_once_with(mock_Object.return_value)
```

Comment: I tried this, but the first assertion now fails with `AssertionError: Expected 'Object' to be called once. Called 0 times.`

Comment: It seems like the `mocker.patch` does not apply to the `function_to_test()` call.

Comment: That's right, you don't mock the function that you're testing, otherwise you're not actually testing anything!

Comment: Sorry, I meant that I don't think `mocker.patch("mymod.Object")` is applying to the initialization of a new Object within `function_to_test`, so the assertion is failing with `AssertionError: Expected 'Object' to be called once. Called 0 times.`

Comment: What does the import of "Object" look like in the module which contains "function_to_test" (in my example I've called the module which contains "function_to_test" as "mymod")?  Is it doing "from othermodule import Object" or is it doing "import othermodule" and then using "othermodule.Object" within "mymod"? This is important for mocker's purposes, because you need to target the correct namespace with the patch.

Comment: It is doing `from othermod import Object`

Comment: In that case this mock, as written, works. You'll have to create a minimal reproducible example of the error before I can help any further.

Comment: That's weird, I just changed it to use `import othermod` and then `othermod.Object` and now the test passes.